# Oracle insert datetime wrong

Tags: oracle

In the oracle, I have field 'time_entered' as date type, I insert a current date time like this, it will give me error. What is the current syntax ? especially I want to insert the time under my timezone, not Oracle server timezone.

Thanks.

```
insert into mytbl( TIME_ENTERED) 
values( SYSDATE);
```

error :

```
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

Comment: Can you please post the _actual_ definition of `mytbl`. I don't believe that Oracle will not allow you to insert `sysdate` into a column that's defined as a date data-type. It's more likely you've got something wrong than Oracle does. [Here's a SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03ec0/1) to prove it.

Comment: As an aside from your error, the Oracle `DATE` datatype is not timezone aware. `SYSDATE` will give you the time on the database server.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities-

1. You are typing the column name `TIME_ENTERED` wrong or there exists a column called `SYSDATE` in the table (which Oracle Shouldn't allow anyways).
2. `mytbl` is a PLSQL Table rather than a database Table.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your timezone with something like:

`ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '-2:00';`

Then you can use:

`insert into mytbl( TIME_ENTERED) values( SYSDATE);`

But be sure that there is no such column on `mytbl` named `SYSDATE`.

Comment: I am sure my table doesn't have "SYSDATE" column. why doesn't work

Comment: Can you try this: `insert into mytbl( TIME_ENTERED) values(NULL);`? Does this work OK?

Comment: Can you create another table with a column named `ABC`, type of `date` and try `insert into newtable(ABC) values(NULL);`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE` will have no effect here.